# Executing an Interface Method Without Knowing Superclass

Tags: java

Here I have a predefined class constructor that accepts a superclass object and a predicate as parameters:

```
public Pathfinder(Character ch, Predicate<Character>) {// Code}
```

I currently have

```
Character myCharacter1 = new Character();
Pathfinder test = new Pathfinder(myCharacter1, character -> UserControllable.class.isAssignableFrom(character.getClass()))
```

to check if the passed character implements the UserControllable interface. I also need to access a boolean method within the UserControllable interface isActive(). How can I use the predicate to check first if a class implements a specific interface, then also call a method from within the interface (that is implemented in all of the subclasses of character) without being able to edit the original Character superclass or the Pathfinder class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `Character` is your own class, which is particularly nasty, because `java.lang.Character` exists and it gets extremely confusing when you make classes that have the same name as a java.lang thing. Please rename that.

At any rate, if you have this:

```
public interface CadensInterface {
    void foo();
}

public class CadensImpl1 implements CadensInterface {
    public void foo() {}
}

public class CadensImpl2 implements CadensInterface {
    public void foo() {}
}
```

then all you need is a cast operation, and there is no need for your `. UserControllable.class.isAssignableFrom`  malarky - that's not idiomatic:

```
x -> {
    if (x instanceof CadensInterface ci) {
        ci.foo();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

That's using java16 features. If you're not that far yet:

```
x -> {
  if (x instanceof CadensInterface) {
    ((CadensInterface) x).foo();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

If, on the other hand, you have something like:

```
public interface CadensInterface {
   // no foo() method here
}

// some classes implementing CadensInterface,
// that all so happen to have a foo() method
```

then, **you cannot do that** - java is nominally typed and doesn't have the concept of 'some class that has a `foo()` method in it. (There is reflection - but you really, really do not want to go there).

There is for example nothing stopping somebody from writing a class that implements CadensInterface that doesn't have a foo method, hence, java won't let you invoke it.

If you think java should gain this feature, do consider this notion:

```
public class Gun {
    public void shoot(Person p) { .... }
}

public class Camera {
    public void shoot(Person p) { .... }
}
```

That may clue you in as to why there is some hesitation on the notion of introducing 'anything that has a foo() method' as a type.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! These aren't the actual classes I'm using but just something I thought up in the moment to try and recreate the problem I'm experiencing.